Sections of an algebraic tensor product of sheaves
Let $\mathcal{O}_X$ be the sheaf of functions on a smooth affine variety $X$. Then, for every Zariski open set $U$ in $X$, there is an isomorphism:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{O}_X(U)\otimes_{\mathbb C}\mathcal{O}_X(U)\cong\mathcal{O}_{X\times X}(U\times U)\quad(1).
\end{equation}
My question is what a section in $(\mathcal{O}_X\otimes_{\mathbb C}\mathcal{O}_X)(U)\cong \mathcal{O}_X(U)\otimes_{\mathbb C}\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ looks like? Is it a function
\begin{align}
f\otimes g: U\times U&\to \mathbb C\quad(2)\\
&(x, y)\mapsto f(x)g(y)
\end{align}
or is it somehow a function
\begin{align}
f\otimes g: \Delta_U\subset U\times U&\to \mathbb C\quad(3)\\
&(x, x)\mapsto f(x)g(x),
\end{align}
where $\Delta_U$ is the diagonal is $U\times U$ and $(x, y)$ is an arbitrary point on the product $U\times U$.
Isomorphism $(1)$ suggests that a section in $(\mathcal{O}_X\otimes_{\mathbb C}\mathcal{O}_X)(U)$ is of the form $(2)$ but the fact that $f\otimes g$ is an element of the space $(\mathcal{O}_X\otimes\mathcal{O}_X)(U)$ confuses me. Someone might be able to provide an insight on this basic issue.
Ultimately, as the tensor product of sheaves is just a presheaf and we need to sheafify, a section of the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X\otimes\mathcal{O}_X$ over a Zariski open set $U$ in $X$ might be a map
\begin{align}
s:U\to \coprod_{x\in U}\mathcal{O}_{X, x}\otimes\mathcal{O}_{X, x}\\
x\mapsto s_x:=f_x\otimes g_x
\end{align}
where $f_x\otimes g_x$ is a germ of $\mathcal{O}_X\otimes\mathcal{O}_X$ at $x$ and thus is represented by a function
\begin{align*}
f\otimes g: V_1\times V_2\to\mathbb C\\
(x', y')\mapsto f(x')g(y') 
\end{align*}
for every pair of Zariski open sets $V_1, V_2$ in $U$ containing $x$ and every pair $(x', y')$ in $V_1\times V_2$. So, which one is the correct interpretation of a section of a tensor product of sheaves?

Someone more familiar with sheaves should answer this, but your notation doesn't distinguish between the external and ordinary tensor product of sheaves which is confusing. The external tensor product is a sheaf on $X \times X$ while the ordinary tensor product is a sheaf on $X$ so you should be clear which one you mean.

Thank you for your remark. I am using implicitly a completed topological tensor product, not the external tensor product. But the completed topological tensor product in the case of smooth affine varieties, in fact in the case of any smooth algebraic varieties reduces to the ordinary algebraic tensor product. So, I am using the ordinary algebraic tensor product in the above. I edited my question and added a third option for a section which might be the right one actually.

Sorry, in that case I really don't understand your notation; if you're using the ordinary tensor product then you're working entirely on $X$, in which case what is $\mathcal{O}_{X \times X}$ doing on the RHS? The external tensor product is the one that satisfies $\mathcal{O}_X \boxtimes \mathcal{O}Y \cong \mathcal{O}{X \times Y}$; here both sides are sheaves on $X \times Y$. For the ordinary tensor product we just have $\mathcal{O}_X \otimes \mathcal{O}_X \cong \mathcal{O}_X$.

At the level of spaces, not sheaves, we have $C^{\infty}(X)\hat{\otimes}{\mathbb C}C^{\infty}(Y)\cong C^{\infty}(X\times Y)$. Consequently, in the algebraic case, we have for the algebraic tensor product $\otimes{\mathbb C}$ that $\mathcal{O}X(U)\otimes{\mathbb C}\mathcal{O}X(U)\cong\mathcal{O}{X\times X}(U\times U)$, correct? There is no sheaf isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_X\otimes \mathcal{O}X\cong\mathcal{O}{X\times X}$, but at the level of sections  over an open set $U$, we have a ring isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\otimes \mathcal{O}X(U)\cong\mathcal{O}{X\times X}(U\times U)$.

Okay, so $\otimes$ is the ordinary tensor product of vector spaces here, and by $\mathcal{O}_X \otimes \mathcal{O}_X$ you mean the tensor product of sheaves of vector spaces, not the tensor product of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules? I think that is quite confusing and should be made more explicit in your notation.

In any case now there's no ambiguity: an element of the vector space $\mathcal{O}X(U) \otimes{\mathbb{C}} \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is, by definition, a finite sum of the form $\sum f_i(x) \otimes g_i(y)$ where $f_i, g_i \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$, so can be interpreted as a function on $U \times U$. This can be used to define the external tensor product. You would confuse yourself less here if you used two different varieties $X, Y$ and considered $\mathcal{O}X(U) \otimes{\mathbb{C}} \mathcal{O}_Y(V)$.

So a section of the sheaf $O_X\otimes_{\mathbb C}\mathcal{O}X$ over an open set $U$ in $X$ is a finite sum of the form $\sum{I}f_i\otimes g_i$, where $f_i, g_i\in\mathcal{O}X(U)$, which can be interpreted as a function on $U\times U$ via the rule $(\sum{I}f_i\otimes g_i)(x, y):=\sum_{I}f_i(x)\otimes g_i(y)$ for every $(x, y)\in U\times U$. Did I understand you correctly?

But the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X\otimes\mathcal{O}_Y$ is defined over $X\times Y$,  whereas $\mathcal{O}_X\otimes\mathcal{O}_X$ is defined over $X$. What is the section of $\mathcal{O}_X\otimes\mathcal{O}X$ over $U$ in $X$? Is it still a finite sum $\sum_if_i(x)\otimes g_i(y)$ as you explained in your comment? Or is it now $\sum{I}f_i(x)\otimes y_i(x)$ because the set $U$ is just one and not two as in $U\times U$?

Maybe I understand what you are doing. You are defining a sheaf $F$ on $X\times X$ by $U\times V\mapsto F(U\times V): =\mathcal{O}X(U)\otimes{\mathbb C}\mathcal{O}_X(V)$, where $U, V$ are open sets in $X$. Then, you define the ordinary sheaf tensor product $\mathcal{O}X\otimes{\mathbb C}\mathcal{O}_X$ on $X$ as the inverse image of $F$: $\mathcal{O}_X\otimes\mathcal{O}_X:=\Delta^* F$, where $\Delta: X\to X\times X$ is the diagonal map. This way, a section of $\mathcal{O}X\otimes{\mathbb C}\mathcal{O}X$ over $U$ is a sum of functions $\sum{I}f_i(x)\otimes g_i(y)$  on $X\times X$?

Hey, you're the one talking about tensor products of vector spaces, not me. $\mathcal{O}X(U) \otimes{\mathbb{C}} \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is just a bare vector space, and I am telling you what its elements look like as a bare vector space. Its elements can be interpreted as functions on $U \times U$ but don't have to be. We don't have to talk about a sheaf at all.

It is very confusing. Ok, what are the sections of the sheaf $\mathcal{O}X\otimes{\mathbb C}\mathcal{O}_X$ over $X$? Is it what I described in the last paragraph of my post?
